# PC laptop without vents in the bottom?

Tags: laptop, pc, cooling

Is there a PC laptop without air vents in the bottom, just like the Macbooks? I've always found those lame; How am I supposed to use it on the top of my lap if I must keep the air vents clear? I actually moved to Mac just because of that. But I'd really like to know if there's a PC option. Thanks.

Comment: Please narrow down the options, providing a budget would be a good start. What kind of performance do you expect from this computer? Edit the question with a list of must haves and nice to haves and don't needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the short answer is:

**Yes**

This list might help:

http://www.ultrabookreview.com/6520-fanless-ultrabooks/

It is a detailed list of laptops that are of a fanless design and would be more in line with what you are asking about.  However, without more details a proper recommendation is hard to give.

Disclaimer: This really isn't a proper answer either, but the question really isn't about hardware recommendations and more a general question that would be easily researched.

Comment: Actually this is (theoretically?) only a subset of all the laptops that the OP has to consider because one can also imagine the vents sitting on the side instead of the bottom.

Comment: There was no mention of side vents, so not included as part of my "answer."  There were a lot of things not mentioned and I'm not even sure that the OP is even looking for something specific, which I also noted.  Its a poor answer, I admit, but it was a poorer question.